He managed to look at ease "despite pigging/being pigging out on" the meat at an excess amount. - different meanings?
Example 1

He managed to look at ease despite pigging out on the meat at an excess amount.

Example 2

He managed to look at ease despite being pigging out on the meat at an excess amount.

Example 3

Although he was pigging out on the meat at an excess amount, he managed to look at ease.

I am sure Example 1 means the same as Example 3. However, does Example 2 mean the same as Example 3?

Example 2 doesn't sound right, and neither does 'at an excess amount'. Try in excessive amounts/quantities.

'Pigging out' is a very casual and informal expression, 'I'd prefer 'gorging himself',  and in any case such expressions already include the idea of greedy excess, so that 'at an excess amount, besides not being good English, is redundant.

Are you suggesting somebody can eat too much, but not too much too much?

@Peter - that would be ridiculous. Something is either excessive or it is not.

Someone can look at ease while stuffing their face; in fact it probably helps to be at ease if you're going to eat like a pig. (Also, while it's sometimes a good idea to explain how excessive something is, "at an excess amount" adds nothing to the meaning, as well as not being idiomatic.)

@StuartF No, because if you are stuffing your face, it is not relaxed and you do not look "at ease", you may feel at ease, I guess.

Right, so the verb is to pig out:
at an excess amount=does not work.
pigging out is by definition an "excess amount" or too much of something.
We say: to pig out on [some type of food].

to pig out on candy
to pig out on steak

and so forth.

He managed to look at ease despite pigging out on the meat.
OR
He managed to look at ease despite eating an excessive amount (or quantity) of meat.


"at an excess amount" needs changing to something like "to excess", so example 3 becomes "Although he was pigging out on the meat to excess, he managed to look at ease". With this change in all examples 1 and 3 do mean the same. Example 2 is gibberish. Why do you think "being" is appropriate here? "being pigged out" is probably what you were going for with "pigged out" as an adjective, which doesn't really work.
